# Algorithm, such as MD5 that is symmetric

Tags: c#-4.0

Algorithm, such as MD5 do you know that any amount of symbols that give it a certain number of coding or hash, and yet reversible (ie symmetrical) is?

Comment: Hash functions are *not* reversible, they are a one way mapping of inputs to a finite sequence of outputs. You are likely interested in asymmetric or symmetric encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reversible hash becomes regular compression (eg. ZIP - .Net has [classes for that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) and/or encryption (eg. AES, [included in .Net as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aes(v=vs.110).aspx)). You can't compress a long piece of text into a short hash and hope to be able to reverse it, since information would become lost - see [Shannon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem), which specifies the limits on how much you can compress information.

Comment: I Would Have A Lot Of Text And I Want To Reduce It With Hashing Or Encryption , And Later I Return It Again.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for encryption. Hashing loses information by design.